# Complex Sql Select statement with latest data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have a process that can be run more than once in a given day or week. I need to figure out the discount amount given on orders that were cancelled.

Having the following two tables

**Transactions**

```
TransactionId,   Date,       Type,    OriginalId
1                2015-1-1    Order    
2                2015-1-1    Order 
3                2015-1-1    Order  
4                2015-1-2    Return   2
5                2015-1-2    Order
```

**DiscountTransactions** - holds records of all transactions that were given a discount at a given Run time.

```
RunId,  TransactionId,   DiscountPercent, Date 
1       1                20%              2015-1-1
1       2                20%              2015-1-1
1       3                20%              2015-1-1
(running program second time, however different discount was applied)
2       1                45%              2015-1-1
2       2                45%              2015-1-1
2       3                45%              2015-1-1
(running program third time, for 2015-1-2)
3       4                45%              2015-1-2
3       5                45%              2015-1-2
```

After having run the program 3 times (twice on 2015-1-1 and once on 2015-1-2) I need to figure out discount percent % given to ORIGINALID for a given TransactionId

So, TransactionId 4 is a Cancallation with OriginalId = 1. So in a select Statement I want to get the Latest valid discount % for that Original Id.

Input to select statement should be a Date. For example Input 2015-1-2 would return a result with one record:

```
TransactionId, OriginalId, Discount%
4              2           45% (45% and NOT 20%) - because it's the latest discount percent given for Transactionid = 1)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if we delete all but records with highest `RunId` from DiscountTransactions the desired result will stay the same?

Comment: Based on your sample data, should the `OriginalId` be `2`?

Comment: Yes 2. Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `JOIN` on `DiscountTransactions.TransactionId = Transactions.OriginalId` and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the latest `DiscountPercent`:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        t.*,
        dt.DiscountPercent,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt.Date DESC, RunId DESC)
    FROM Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN DiscountTransactions dt
        ON dt.TransactionId = t.OriginalId
    WHERE
        t.Date = CAST('20150102' AS DATE)
        AND t.Type = 'Return'
)
SELECT
    TransactionId,
    OriginalId,
    DiscountPercent
FROM Cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thinking about it now, can i use current run id? In this case 3 instead of date?

Comment: In the `WHERE` clause? Sure!